# Every elementary submodel of $H(\aleph_1)$ is transitive

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I am trying to solve the first part of Exercise II.17.30 in Kunen's *Foundations of Mathematics* which asks:

> Prove that every $A \preccurlyeq H(\aleph_1)$ is transitive.

Here we are working over the language $\mathcal{L} = \{\in\}$ of set theory, and $H(\aleph_1)$ is the set of hereditarily countable sets (i.e. those whose transitive closures are countable).  The symbol $\preccurlyeq$ denotes "is an elementary submodel of".

Let's try the contrapositive: suppose $A$ is not transitive, so there are sets $u \in A$, $v \in u$ and $v \notin A$.  I presume I want to find a formula $\varphi$ so that $A \vDash \varphi(u)$ but $H(\aleph_1) \nvDash \varphi(u)$.  I am having trouble seeing how I can detect that $u$ contains an element $v$ which is not in $A$, since as far as $A$ is concerned, $v$ does not exist and $u$ behaves just like $u \cap A$.

If $u$ is a finite set, say of size 5, then if $\varphi(x)$ is the formula "$x$ has 5 distinct elements", we would have $H(\aleph_1) \vDash \varphi(u)$ but $A \vDash \neg \varphi(u)$.  Something similar works if $u \cap A$ is finite.  But if $u \cap A$ is infinite I don't see how to proceed.

Kunen gives the hint: "If $\emptyset \ne x \in A$, then there is an $f \in A$ such that $f :\omega \overset{\text{onto}}{\to} x$."  I can't see how that helps.  (It might be intended as a hint to the second part of the question, which asks for a countable transitive $A$ with a singleton subset that is not $\Delta_0$.)

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Thank you. I never knew this result, and it made a very nice dessert for an evening of grading homework!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:** (for Kunen's hint)

Let $A\prec H(\omega_1)$ and let $x\in A$.

First note that $\omega\in A$ and certainly $\omega\subseteq A$. Now use the hint, $x$ satisfies the formula *"There exists a function $f$ whose domain is $\omega$ and $x$ is its range"*; use elementarity to deduce that such $f$ exists in $A$, and that the "true range" (in $H(\omega_1)$, that is) of this $f$ is $x$. Conclude that $x\subseteq A$.

Comment: Got it.  I was thinking about the hint all wrong somehow.  The point is that such a surjection $f_0$ exists in the model $H(\aleph_1)$, hence a (possibly different) surjection $f$ exists in the submodel $A$.  Now if $A$ were not transitive, then such an $f$ would not be surjective in the extension $H(\aleph_1)$, a contradiction.

Comment: Yes. That's the point! (In the meantime I slightly revised my hint, but I see it was unnecessary.)

Comment: By the way, if you don't mind me asking, why are you studying set theory? (I'm all in favor of that, I'm just interested in why - in a good way, don't worry!)

Comment: Mostly just for fun!  I mainly work in probability theory, but I've found from time to time that foundational issues like independence results provide helpful guidance in thinking about measurability questions, etc.  But I only saw such results as black boxes and had no idea of the underlying theory, so I thought this summer I would try to teach myself some of the basics of modern logic and set theory.  I have Kunen's revised edition of *Set Theory* next so you may see many more such questions from me!

Comment: That's wonderful. I'll be happy to see more fun questions! Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the good wishes!

Comment: The same argument shows that the result holds with $L_{\omega_1}$ in place of $H(\omega_1)$. This version appears for example in Devlin's constructibility book. The argument is really useful in many settings.