# Countable elementary submodels

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I'm having some trouble understanding elementary submodels.

Let $H_\chi$ be the set of all sets which are hereditarily of cardinality $<\chi$. Let $\textbf{N}=(N,\in)$ be a countable elementary submodel of $(H_{\chi} ,\in)$ Moreover let $p\in N$ and $q\in H_{\chi}$ such that $\lvert p\triangle q\rvert$ is finite. Under what sort of circumstances is $q\in N$?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of questions here, some of them very basic about the nature of elementary submodels of $H(\chi)$. I would suggest trying to remove any remnants of forcing from this question and focus instead on your particular concerns. (For example, your $q$ just results from a finite change of $p$, so you could ask whether (or under what sort of circumstances) does an element of $H(\chi)$ which has finite symmetric difference with an element of $N$ also belong to $N$.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited the question.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/811895/30222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are equivalent:

- $(i)$ $q\in N$,
- $(ii)$ $p\Delta q\subseteq N$,
- $(iii)$ $p\Delta q\in N$.

$(ii)\rightarrow(iii)$ is easy, since by assumption $p\Delta q$ is finite - it's easy to show that the union of finitely many elements of $N$ is in $N$.

For $(iii)\rightarrow(i)$, note that $N$ contains an element $r$ which $N$ thinks satisfies $r=p\Delta(p\Delta q)$ - by elementarity, we in fact have $r=p\Delta(p\Delta q)$, but this is just $q$.

For $(i)\rightarrow (iii)$, if $q\in N$ then $N$ contains some element $s$ which $N$ thinks is $p\Delta q$ - so by elementarity, $s=p\Delta q$.

Finally, for $(iii)\rightarrow (ii)$, this follows from the following more general fact:

> Suppose $N$ is a countable elementary submodel of $H_\chi$ and $X\in N$ is countable. Then $X\subseteq N$.

Pf: By elementarity, $N$ contains some $f$ which $N$ thinks is a surjection from $\omega^N$ to $X$. But $\omega^N=\omega$, so by elementarity $f$ is in fact a surjection from $\omega$ to $X$. But then each $x\in X$ is of the form $f(n)$ for some $n\in\omega$, and $\omega\subseteq M$ - so for each $n\in\omega$, $f(n)\in N$.

---

Note that these conditions aren't vacuous. For example, fix $p\in N$ and $x\in H_\chi\setminus N$. Then $q:=p\cup\{x\}\not\in N$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. One more question: Let $X\subseteq N$. Is $\cup X\in N$ even if we don't assume that $X$ is finite? Can I do something like this: If $\chi$ is large enough, $(H_\chi,\in)$ satisfies the axiom of union. So
$$
(H_\chi,\in)\models \forall X\in H_\chi (\cup X\in H_\chi)
$$
Since $N$ is an elementary submodel, we have that
$$
\textbf{N}\models \forall X\in N (\cup X\in N).
$$
So $\cup X\in N$. Or did I understand something totally wrong?

Comment: @Rungo Yes, that's right, although you should really think of it as a two-step argument: first, note that $H_\chi$ thinks that for every set $X$, a unique set $Y$ exists satisfying a certain first-order property $\varphi(X, Y)$ (specifically, $\varphi(X, Y)$ says "$Y=\cup X$"). By elementarity, $N$ contains some element $Y'$ such that $N\models \varphi(X, Y')$. By elementarity, this means $H_\chi\models \varphi(X, Y')$. So $Y'=Y$. I would emphasize both uses of elementarity, when thinking about elementary submodels.

Comment: Note that this doesn't use any property of unions, other than the fact that the map "$X\mapsto \cup X$" is first-order definable.